# pbkdf2 and hash comparison

Tags: python, hash, comparison, pbkdf2

I use mitsuhiko's implementation of pbkdf2 for password hashing:

```
def pbkdf2_bin(data, salt, iterations=1000, keylen=24, hashfunc=None):
    """Returns a binary digest for the PBKDF2 hash algorithm of `data`
    with the given `salt`.  It iterates `iterations` time and produces a
    key of `keylen` bytes.  By default SHA-1 is used as hash function,
    a different hashlib `hashfunc` can be provided.
    """
    hashfunc = hashfunc or hashlib.sha1
    mac = hmac.new(data, None, hashfunc)
    def _pseudorandom(x, mac=mac):
        h = mac.copy()
        h.update(x)
        return map(ord, h.digest())
    buf = []
    for block in xrange(1, -(-keylen // mac.digest_size) + 1):
        rv = u = _pseudorandom(salt + _pack_int(block))
        for i in xrange(iterations - 1):
            u = _pseudorandom(''.join(map(chr, u)))
            rv = starmap(xor, izip(rv, u))
        buf.extend(rv)
    return ''.join(map(chr, buf))[:keylen]
```

This function returns binary digest which is then encoded in base64 and saved to database. Also that base64 string is set as a cookie when a user logs in.

This function is used for password hashes comparison:

```
def comparePasswords(password1, password2):
    if len(password1) != len(password2):
        return False
    diff = 0
    for x, y in izip(password1, password2):
        diff |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)
    return diff == 0
```

I wonder if there is any difference in comparison of binary hashes and base64 strings in terms of security? For example when a user logs in, I calculate binary digest of submitted password, decode base64 string from the database and then compare two binary hashes, but in case the user has a cookie with base64 string, I directly compare it with the a string from the database.

The second question is about salt:

os.urandom returns binary string, but before it is used in hash generation I also encode it in base64. Is there any reason why I shouldn't do this and use salt in binary form?

Comment: To any one reading this: this is an old question and **PBKDF2 is no longer the recommended password hashing algorithm** (although it is far better than many broken schemes people use in practice). Nowadays this title belong to **Argon2i**, the winner of the password hashing competition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To answer question 1**: There's no major security difference when comparing bytes vs comparing a base64 encoded string... you're just comparing `n` or `n*4/3` elements. The runtime will be `4/3` longer using base64, but the amount of time is still trivial :)

That said, there was a python developer [discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue15061) regarding a similar "constant time" comparison function, and they hit upon a few VM-level gotchas - if your input is a `unicode` string rather than `bytes`, and especially if the unicode contains non-ASCII characters, there may still be some subtle timing attacks (orders of magnitude less than the short-circuit-equality attack). Because of that, I'd stick to bytes if possible (whether binary data or ASCII-encoded base64 data). 
However, I wouldn't worry *too much* in the case of PBKDF2, since the [timing attack](http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/) that comparison function was designed to defeat applies more to HMAC signing, rather than password hash verification... but better to be safe than sorry.

**To answer question 2**: For insecure constructions such as `md5(salt+password)`, encoding the salt first would allow an attacker to use existing ASCII md5 tables to attack the entire digest, where a raw binary salt would make such tables useless. However, PBKDF2-HMAC does enough mangling that the only thing which matters is that the salt contains `n` bits of entropy - whether it's in the form of `n/8` raw bytes, or `n/6` base64 chars doesn't affect security.

**Other notes**: 
I just wanted to add a few other points relating to what you posted...

1. For security purposes I'd strongly recommend using SHA256/512 instead of SHA1 as the PBKDF2-HMAC hash function, and >= 10,000 rounds (as of 2012), for security.
2. The idea of sending the digest over in a cookie (even w/o the salt) strikes me as potentially insecure... if someone steals that cookie (e.g. cross-site scripting attack), they could potentially log in as the user (though I don't know the rest your application's security setup). Using a session layer with a randomly generated session id (e.g. [Beaker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Beaker/)) might be a good alternative.
3. I'd recommend using the Passlib [PBKDF2](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.utils.pbkdf2.html#passlib.utils.pbkdf2.pbkdf2) and [consteq](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.utils.html#passlib.utils.consteq) implementations, it's PBKDF2 routine is about 5x faster than mitsuhiko's, and can take advantage of [M2Crypto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto/) if present. *(disclaimer: I'm the author of Passlib)*. It's also got a ready-made [pbkdf2-sha256](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html) password hashing function, though that won't be quite as much use if you're sending the digest out in the cookie.

Comment: Thank you very much Eli for your time and for sharing your knowledge! I'm impressed how responsive are people on stackoverflow.

I already use SHA256 and I'll increase iterations to 10000 rounds. Also I was looking at sessions, but I decided to stick with simplicity and use cookies, because my app is a simple single-user blog with anonymouse readers and 1 admin, who must be authenticated.

Comment: There is an interesting issue with unicode strings. As I can understand from the discussion you mentioned, the problem can appear if we compare 2 unicode strings as we need to encode them before comparison. I wonder, how it can affect me? My input is a password from POST. It's a unicode string which I encode for HMAC to work and then I save it as a hash:
`formData = web.input()
password = pbkdf2_bin(formData.password.encode('utf-8'), user.salt, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256)`
I don't compare unicode strings directly, instead I compare hashes in binary or base64 form.

Comment: The unicode timing issue isn't really applicable to your case (or most password hashing comparisons in general), since it requires the attacker have some level of control over both inputs to `comparePasswords()`. Looking back, I didn't mean to devote quite as much text as I did to the issue... I wanted to raise awareness of the flaw, but I suspect I wrote too much :)